# center Label in v-text-field

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

hello I have tried different solutions to center the label in my v-text-field unfortunately none of them worked.
please find the code below :

html code

`<v-text-field dark class="centered-input" label="your code"></v-text-field>`

css code

```
    .centered-input >>>  label {
        color: white;
        font-size:20px;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Is there a way to align my label with vuetify

Comment: it is unclear what you are trying to achieve, center within what context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `text-align: center` applies correctly. The text gets quite centered inside this box:

[image: label box]

Upon inspection, you'll notice the label is absolutely positioned in its parent and, to center it horizontally relative to its parent, you'll need to override its `left` and `transform` values. Here's the necessary SCSS:

```scss
.v-text-field.centered-input .v-label {
  left: 50% !important;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  &.v-label--active {
    transform: translateY(-18px) scale(.75) translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```

See it working here: https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/rNOObmN

**Note**: the `!important` is, unfortunately, necessary, as the `left` value is applied inline, on the element, via JavaScript. Gotta love Vuetify!